# How do I fix failed to write error while exporting data to ragged right flat file?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that exports data to a text file of format *Ragged Right*. While runnig the package, I get the error **`Failed to write out column name for column "Column0."`**

Here are the Flat file connectioon Manager details:

```
General tab:
-----------
Format --> Ragged Right  
Header Row Delimiter --> {CR}-{LF} 

Columns tab:
-----------
Font --> Consolas
```

I have tried to set the delay validation property to true but the package still fails.

Comment: all the columns are of string datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue: I changed Header row Delimiter to `{cr}-{LF}`.

And inside **Advanced Tab**, I have done small changes, like keeping `inputColumnWidth` and `outputcolumnwidth` same.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have a text file with fixed width and column headers in the file whereas the column name and the data length definition disagree e.g.

[image]

The fix is in making the data length fit the column description.